# How many training samples should I take for an object detection model with 62 classes?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection, yolo

I'm trying to train a YOLOv3 model for 62 classes using https://github.com/wizyoung/YOLOv3_TensorFlow.

How many samples should I take for each class.
I'm using a Nvidia GTX 1050Ti GPU so what should be my batch size with each image of 300*300 size?
Is 80-20 train/test split ideal?

Answer (score 1):

The 80-20% train-test(val) split is dependent on the number of samples, not on the number of classes. The more data you have, the bigger the discrepancy percentage between train and test(val) it can be (for millions of samples data you can have 95%---5% split)

Normally, at least (minimum) number of 200 bounding_boxes_annotations per object should be present. That is, each of your classes should have at least 200 annotations.

1050Ti has only 4GB VRAM. Depending on your image_size, you can increase or decrease the batch_size. However, take into consideration that you do not have very much VRAM available, most likely(decrease it to 1 if you have OOM issues) a batch_size of 2 for images of 300x300 will be the maximum you can achieve.